# Sum cols where row value is equal to header - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to sum columns in a pandas df where the column is equal to a specific value. Using the df below, where `['X'] == 'GrV'`, I want to sum cols `('GrV A', 'GrV B')`. But I'm returning `nan` values.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'X' : ['GrV', 'GrX', 'GrY', 'GrZ', 'GrV', 'GrX', 'GrY', 'GrZ'],  
    'GrV A' : [4, 2, 6, 5, 1, 2, 5, 6],                  
    'GrX A' : [3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 5, 6, 2], 
    'GrY A' : [5, 2, 2, 6, 5, 1, 5, 4],
    'GrZ A' : [1, 2, 5, 5, 2, 1, 5, 4], 
    'GrV B' : [4, 2, 6, 5, 1, 2, 5, 6],                  
    'GrX B' : [3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 5, 6, 2], 
    'GrY B' : [5, 2, 2, 6, 5, 1, 5, 4],
    'GrZ B' : [1, 2, 5, 5, 2, 1, 5, 4],                            
        })

df['Total'] = df.loc[(df['X'] == 'GrV'), ('GrV A', 'GrV B')].sum()
df['Total'] = df.loc[(df['X'] == 'GrX'), ('GrX A', 'GrX B')].sum()
df['Total'] = df.loc[(df['X'] == 'GrY'), ('GrY A', 'GrY B')].sum()
df['Total'] = df.loc[(df['X'] == 'GrZ'), ('GrZ A', 'GrZ B')].sum()
```

Intended Output:

```
     X  GrV A  GrX A  GrY A  GrZ A  GrV B  GrX B  GrY B  GrZ B  Total
0  GrV      4      3      5      1      4      3      5      1      8
1  GrX      2      4      2      2      2      4      2      2      8
2  GrY      6      5      2      5      6      5      2      5      4
3  GrZ      5      1      6      5      5      1      6      5     10
4  GrV      1      2      5      2      1      2      5      2      2
5  GrX      2      5      1      1      2      5      1      1     10
6  GrY      5      6      5      5      5      6      5      5     10
7  GrZ      6      2      4      4      6      2      4      4      8
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it by using `filter` to get the columns Gr, use `where` the first element of column name obtained by `split`( to get the GrV, GrX, ... part) is equal to the column X and `sum` along the column:

```
df['Total'] = (df.filter(like='Gr')
                 .where(lambda x: df['X'].to_numpy()[:, None]
                                  == x.columns.str.split(' ').str[0].to_numpy())
                 .sum(axis=1)
              )
print (df)
     X  GrV A  GrX A  GrY A  GrZ A  GrV B  GrX B  GrY B  GrZ B  Total
0  GrV      4      3      5      1      4      3      5      1    8.0
1  GrX      2      4      2      2      2      4      2      2    8.0
2  GrY      6      5      2      5      6      5      2      5    4.0
3  GrZ      5      1      6      5      5      1      6      5   10.0
4  GrV      1      2      5      2      1      2      5      2    2.0
5  GrX      2      5      1      1      2      5      1      1   10.0
6  GrY      5      6      5      5      5      6      5      5   10.0
7  GrZ      6      2      4      4      6      2      4      4    8.0
```

Comment: Thanks for this but I'm getting a valueError: `ValueError: Array conditional must be same shape as self`

Answer (score 2):

This is one way about it : append column X to the index, get a pairing of index and columns where values in the new index can be found in the columns, use the resulting values to index the dataframe(with `loc`), stack, unstack and get the totals

```
#append column X to the index
df = df.set_index("X",append=True)

from itertools import product

#get pairing of index and column, where index is in column
index = [(first,second, last)
         for (first,second), last 
         in product(df.index,df.columns)
         if second in last]

#stack, index with the index variable,
#unstack, get the sum
#and assign to Total
df['Total'] = df.stack().loc[index].unstack().sum(axis=1)

df

           GrV A    GrX A   GrY A   GrZ A   GrV B   GrX B   GrY B   GrZ B   Total
X                                   
0   GrV      4       3       5       1       4       3       5      1       8.0
1   GrX      2       4       2       2       2       4       2      2       8.0
2   GrY      6       5       2       5       6       5       2      5       4.0
3   GrZ      5       1       6       5       5       1       6      5      10.0
4   GrV      1       2       5       2       1       2       5      2       2.0
5   GrX      2       5       1       1       2       5       1      1      10.0
6   GrY      5       6       5       5       5       6       5      5      10.0
7   GrZ      6       2       4       4       6       2       4      4       8.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way of doing it:

```
for col in df['X'].tolist():
    df['Total_'+col] = np.where(df['X']==col, df[col+' A'] + df[col+' B'], np.NaN)

cols = [col for col in df.columns if col.startswith('Total_')]
df['Total'] = df[cols].sum(axis=1)
df.drop(columns=cols, inplace=True)
print(df)

     X  GrV A  GrX A  GrY A  GrZ A  GrV B  GrX B  GrY B  GrZ B  Total
0  GrV      4      3      5      1      4      3      5      1    8.0
1  GrX      2      4      2      2      2      4      2      2    8.0
2  GrY      6      5      2      5      6      5      2      5    4.0
3  GrZ      5      1      6      5      5      1      6      5   10.0
4  GrV      1      2      5      2      1      2      5      2    2.0
5  GrX      2      5      1      1      2      5      1      1   10.0
6  GrY      5      6      5      5      5      6      5      5   10.0
7  GrZ      6      2      4      4      6      2      4      4    8.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Let us try `melt` with `groupby`

```
s=df.reset_index().melt(['index','X']).loc[lambda x : x['X']==x['variable'].str.split(' ').str[0]].groupby('index').value.sum()
df['new']=s
df
     X  GrV A  GrX A  GrY A  GrZ A  GrV B  GrX B  GrY B  GrZ B  new
0  GrV      4      3      5      1      4      3      5      1    8
1  GrX      2      4      2      2      2      4      2      2    8
2  GrY      6      5      2      5      6      5      2      5    4
3  GrZ      5      1      6      5      5      1      6      5   10
4  GrV      1      2      5      2      1      2      5      2    2
5  GrX      2      5      1      1      2      5      1      1   10
6  GrY      5      6      5      5      5      6      5      5   10
7  GrZ      6      2      4      4      6      2      4      4    8
```